# Moq.Verifiable: Nunit. Не срабатывает нужное количество раз

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Есть два метода

```
public void AddToSearchIndex<TEntity>(TEntity model) where TEntity : 
{
    _repository.Insert(model);
}

public void AddToSearchIndex<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> models) where TEntity : class
{
    foreach (var model in models)    
        _repository.Insert(model);
}
```

Пытаюсь написать тесты.

```
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            users = new List<User>
            {
                new User { Id = 1, Login = "user1", Email = "user1@mail.net" },
                new User { Id = 2, Login = "user2", Email = "user2@mail.net" },
                new User { Id = 3, Login = "user3", Email = "user3@mail.net" },
                new User { Id = 4, Login = "user4", Email = "user4@mail.net" },
                new User { Id = 5, Login = "user5", Email = "user5@mail.net" }
            };

            mockRepo = new Mock<ISearchRepository>();
            sut = new LuceneSearchService(mockRepo.Object);
        }

        private IEnumerable<User> users;
        private Mock<ISearchRepository> mockRepo;
        private ISearchService sut;
```

Данный тест проходит

```
[Test]
public void AddIndex_InsertNewIndexVerify_Return_Once()
{
    var user = new User();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.Insert<User>(user)).Verifiable();

    sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);

    mockRepo.Verify(v => v.Insert<User>(user), Times.Once);
}
```

А вот этот уже нет

```
[Test]
public void AddIndex_InsertNewIndexIEnumerableVerify_Return_UsersCount()
{
    var user = new User();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.Insert<User>(user)).Verifiable();

    //не работает
    sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(users);

    //не работает
    //foreach (var item in users)
    //    sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(item);

    //работает
    //sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);
    //sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);
    //sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);
    //sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);
    //sut.AddToSearchIndex<User>(user);

    mockRepo.Verify(v => v.Insert<User>(user), Times.Exactly(users.Count<User>()));
}
```

При этом выводит следующее

```
Message: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 5 times, but was 0 times: v => v.Insert<User>(User)

Configured setups: 
x => x.Insert<User>(User)

Performed invocations: 
ISearchRepository.Insert<User>(User)
ISearchRepository.Insert<User>(User)
ISearchRepository.Insert<User>(User)
ISearchRepository.Insert<User>(User)
ISearchRepository.Insert<User>(User)
```

Moq и NUnit еще только разбираю, опыта не много. Есть какая-то тонкость? Или я чего-то просто не вижу?

Comment: Тест исправил, вместо конкретного User вставил It.IsAny<User>() и тест прошел. Но почему так, так и не понял. Буду курить moq. Буду крайне благодарен, если кто-то направит